# Bind some inner nodes values from XML to data gridview (win application)

Tags: c#

i want to load some nodes to my data grid view from XML file.
i want to select just (DeviceName , Cod , Office ) from every record and bind to data grid view.
how can i do it?

```
<tbl_Device>

<record  id="1">

<DeviceName>BB</DeviceName>
<Cod>fds</Cod>
<Office>orrange</Office>
<UserName>Sali</UserName>
<DateTset>1/23/2014</DateTset>
<FirstLength>10</FirstLength>
<Area>62.8318530717959</Area>
<Speed>13</Speed>
<UnitX>2</UnitX>
<UnitY>0</UnitY>

</record>



<record id="2">

<DeviceName>mm</DeviceName>
<Cod>0020</Cod>
<Office>apple</Office>
<UserName>jack</UserName>
<DateTset>4/23/2014</DateTset>
<FirstLength>90</FirstLength>
<Area>62.8318530717959</Area>
<Speed>24</Speed>
<UnitX>0</UnitX>
<UnitY>1</UnitY>

</record>

.
.
.

 </tbl_Device>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like below

```
   System.Data.DataSet ds;
   ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
   ds.ReadXml("D:\\myxmlfile.xml");
   ds.Tables[0].Columns.Remove("UserName");
   ds.Tables[0].Columns.Remove("DateTset");
   ds.Tables[0].Columns.Remove("FirstLength");
   ds.Tables[0].Columns.Remove("Area");
   ds.Tables[0].Columns.Remove("Speed");
   ds.Tables[0].Columns.Remove("UnitX");
   ds.Tables[0].Columns.Remove("UnitY");
   GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

another way you just using loop fill the cell of gridview.